# AngularJs: Passing "controller as" to a service, is this good practice?

Tags: angularjs, anti-patterns

Let's say I have a controller like:

```
angular.app("myapp",[]).controller("MyCtrl", function (MyService){

         var vm = this;

         vm.value1 = something();
         vm.array1 = somethingElse;

        //notice that I pass the whole controller as object to the service.
        MyService.getData(vm); 

         //do something with data...
         doWithNewData(vm.elementCreatedByMyService);

}). etc...
```

Now, to pass the vm itself seems to have sense, because I don't need to pass several values and  several controllers call this service.

It seems overkill because, of course, vm has much more than the elements used in the service.

Also, this favors reuse (As I discovered in production).

My questions then: Is this an antipattern or is a valid use of a "controller as" object?
Now, if this is an antipattern, what should do instead?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really criminal here to call it antipattern. But there's nothing really good also because it requires the service to be aware of `vm`, any changes to existing `vm` properties will effect controller's scope (not necessary in a desirable way).

> Now, if this is an antipattern, what should do instead?

Pass local variable to the service and incorporate it into controller's scope when needed?